# Cambiar valor de 'meta' en <link> css despues de onload

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

tengo un problema.

*Estoy tratando de usar carga CSS asincrona para optimizar mis elementos graficos.*

En el `<head>` de mi html tengo varios links de .css (ejemplo:)

```
<link id="cs1" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ZooCss.css" media="none" onload="cambiarMedia()"/>
```

La función `cambiarMedia()` esta mas arriba de los links:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cambiarMedia() {
        if (document.getElementById("cs1").getAttribute('media') === 'none') {
            document.getElementById("cs1").setAttribute('media', 'all');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Basicamente lo que quiero que haga es cambiar el valor de `meta` a `all`.
Los problemas con los que me choque:

1. Asi como esta la funcion `cambiarMedia` Visual Studio me tira el siguente error:

> 'ASP.default_aspx' no contiene una definición de `cambiarMedia` ni se
>    encontró ningún método de extensión `cambiarMedia` que acepte un
>    primer argumento de tipo 'ASP.default_aspx' (¿falta una directiva
>    using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

2. Si llego a solucionar este error, también me gustaría transformar la función `cambiarMedia` para que sea reutilizable para todos los CSS's.
   Para no volver a escribirla por cada ID del CSS.

Me pueden dar una mano con eso por favor?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="
```

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", c);
function c(){
 var css = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("link"));
 css.forEach(e => {e.media = "all";});
 console.log(document.getElementById("paraprobar").media); // probando que todos se hayan cambiado..
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" media="none"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" media="none"/>
<link id="paraprobar" rel="stylesheet" href="" media="none"/>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a probar.La funcion window.addEventListener la pongo entre tags <script> en mi head?

Comment: Todo eso es código javascript, por lo cual sí hiria en la etiqueta script, pero no te recomiendo en absoluto usar javascript dentro del HTML, hazlo separado de este.

Comment: Te referis a crear un archivo.js, pegar el codigo ahi y despues incluirlo al html? Otra pregunta, por que no conviene en absoluto usar js dentro del html? Gracias